# StackExchange.Redis timeout

Tags: azure, redis, timeout, stackexchange.redis

Production environment is on Azure, using `Redis Cache Standard 2.5GB`.

**Example 1**

> System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. --->
>   StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout performing SETNX
>   User.313123, inst: 49, mgr: Inactive, err: never, queue: 0, qu: 0, qs:
>   0, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 0, ar: 0, clientName: PRD-VM-WEB-2,
>   serverEndpoint: Unspecified/Construct3.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,
>   keyHashSlot: 15649, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=1,Max=1000), WORKER:
>   (Busy=1,Free=32766,Min=1,Max=32767) (Please take a look at this
>   article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts:
>   http://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts) at
>   StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message
>   message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in
>   c:\code\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line
>   2120 at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message,
>   ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in
>   c:\code\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\RedisBase.cs:line
>   81

**Example 2**

> StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout performing GET
>   ForumTopic.33831, inst: 1, mgr: Inactive, err: never, queue: 2, qu: 0,
>   qs: 2, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 0, ar: 0, clientName: PRD-VM-WEB-2,
>   serverEndpoint: Unspecified/Construct3.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,
>   keyHashSlot: 5851, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=1,Max=1000), WORKER:
>   (Busy=1,Free=32766,Min=1,Max=32767) (Please take a look at this
>   article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts:
>   http://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)    at
>   StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message
>   message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in
>   c:\code\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line
>   2120    at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message
>   message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in
>   c:\code\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\RedisBase.cs:line
>   81    at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.StringGet(RedisKey key,
>   CommandFlags flags) in
>   c:\code\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\RedisDatabase.cs:line
>   1647    at
>   C3.Code.Controls.Application.Caching.Distributed.DistributedCacheController.Get[T](String
>   cacheKey) in
>   C:\Construct.net\Source\C3Alpha2\Code\Controls\Application\Caching\Distributed\DistributedCacheController.cs:line
>   115    at
>   C3.Code.Controls.Application.Caching.Manager.Manager.Get[T](String
>   key, Func`1 getFromExternFunction, Boolean skipLocalCaches) in
>   C:\Construct.net\Source\C3Alpha2\Code\Controls\Application\Caching\Manager\Manager.cs:line
>   159    at C3.PageControls.Forums.TopicRender.Page_Load(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Construct.net\Source\C3Alpha2\PageControls\Forums\TopicRender.ascx.cs:line
>   40    at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

These errors are sporadic, several times a day.

Is this an Azure network blip, or something I can reduce?  Looking at the numbers in the error doesn't seem anything out of the ordinary, and the server load never seems to go above 7% as reported by Azure.

**Redis connection**

```
internal static class RedisController
{
    private static readonly object GetConnectionLock = new object();
    public static ConnectionMultiplexer GetConnection()
    {
        if (Global.RedisConnection == null)
        {
            lock (GetConnectionLock)
            {
                if (Global.RedisConnection == null)
                {
                    Global.RedisConnection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(
                        Settings.Deployment.RedisConnectionString);
                }
            }
        }
        return Global.RedisConnection;
    }
```

Comment: Therre are a few steps how to investigate Azure Redis timeout issues, it might help: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/investigating-timeout-exceptions-in-stackexchange-redis-for-azure-redis-cache/

Comment: How many requests are you making per second? I wonder if there is rate throttling to prevent suspected DoS attacks. Have you tried running this on another service; aws, rackspace, local, to see if you still get timeouts?

Comment: @varlogtim can't test this on another infrastructure as it's being throw in production - dev server never seen this error (am using Redis in dev as well).

Comment: @TomGullen - Could you post the code snippet where you open the redis client?

Comment: @janniks posted it

Comment: I'm beginning to think this is just a bug with the StackExchange.Redis client.  I have [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936394/bursts-of-redistimeoutexception-using-stackexchange-redis) and haven't gotten anywhere with it.  It's causing a lot of problems on our production servers.

Comment: @MikeChristensen can you share how you're connecting to the Redis client?

Comment: I also asked Mike in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936394/bursts-of-redistimeoutexception-using-stackexchange-redis) It might be a similar issue.
@MikeChristensen - You can try the proposed answers below

Comment: @TomGullen are you able to provide a sample of your connection string with instance and secrets blanked out. Also where is the cache client, is it a VM in Azure, Web App, on-premises... I'm guessing you are using an older version of the NuGet, since there is v2 released since this post, but if you could confirm the version that would be great.

Comment: @BernieWhite our connection string is `xxxxxxx.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=xxxxxx=,ssl=True,abortConnect=False,allowAdmin=True`

We have two VM's in Azure running the webapp that use Redis.  We're using StackExchange.Redis 2.0.513

Any help much appreciated, we're at our wits end here.  We've changed in `Application_Start ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(10, 10)` from default but seems to of not made any difference.

Comment: We have same problem and solved it for awhile by storing some data in memory cache and reducing number of reads from redis. I am thinkig of to try some other client instead of stack exchange or to use redis server instead of service.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 3 scenarios that can cause timeouts, and it is hard to know which is in play:

1. the library is tripping over; in particular, there are known issues relating to the TLS implementation and how we handle the read loop in the v1.* version of the library - something that we have invested a *lot* of time working on for v2.* (however: it is *not* always trivial to update to v2, especially if you're using the library as part of other code that depend on a specific version)
2. the server/network is tripping over; this is a very real possibility - looking at "slowlog" can help if it is server-side, but I don't have any visibility of that
3. the server and network are fine, and the library is doing what it can, but there are some huge blobs flying between client and server that are delaying other operations; this is something that I'm making changes to help identify *right now*, and if this shows itself to be a common problem, we'll perhaps look at making better use of concurrent connections (which doesn't increase bandwidth, but can reduce latency for blocked operations) - this would be a v2 only change, note

Comment: Thanks for your help Marc.  We've managed to reduce errors from ~50-100 daily to zero by setting WorkerThreads and CompletionPortThreads to 200 (from default value which I'm assuming is 1) in `Application_Start` with `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(200, 200);`

Guessing this fits into category 2?

Comment: @TomGullen hmmm... that might be "category 4" :) btw - I added some new support yesterday to help identify / call out "category 3" - https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/commit/7de4483509e56ba5798e56f062198b229659ff8c

Comment: Thanks for your help Marc and wonderful libraries as always!  Happy this now appears to be resolved from what I can observe for last 2 days.  Just as a side note Azure support have analysed server/network performance and confirmed there was no unusual behaviour at the time errors were being thrown.

Answer (score 6):

#### Lazy Connection

As a best practice make sure you are using the following pattern to connect to the StackExchange Redis client:

```
private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() => {
    return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("cachename.redis.cache.windows.net,ssl=true,abortConnect=false,password=password");
});

public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection {
    get {
        return lazyConnection.Value;
    }
}
```

If the above does not work, there are some more debugging routes described in [Source 1](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/investigating-timeout-exceptions-in-stackexchange-redis-for-azure-redis-cache/), regarding region, bandwidth and NuGet package versions among others.

#### IO Threads

Another option could be to increase the minimum IO threads. It’s often recommend to set the minimum configuration value for IOCP and WORKER threads to something larger than the default value. There is no one-size-fits-all guidance on what this value should be because the right value for one application will be too high/low for another application. A good starting place is 200 or 300, then test and tweak as needed.

**How to configure this setting:**

- In **ASP.NET**, use the `minIoThreads` configuration setting under the [`<processModel>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w2sway1(v=vs.71).aspx) configuration element in machine.config. According to Microsoft, you can’t change this value per site by editing your web.config (even when you could do it in the past), so the value that you choose here is the value that all your .NET sites will use. Please note that you don’t need to add every property if you have autoConfig set to false, just putting `autoConfig="false"` and overriding the value is enough:
  `<processModel autoConfig="false" minIoThreads="250" />`

> **Important Note:** the value specified in this configuration element is a per-core setting. For example, if you have a 4 core machine and want your minIOThreads setting to be 200 at runtime, you would use `<processModel minIoThreads="50"/>`.

- **Outside of ASP.NET**, use the [ThreadPool.SetMinThreads()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads?view=netcore-2.0#System_Threading_ThreadPool_SetMinThreads_System_Int32_System_Int32_) API.
- In **.Net Core**, add Environment Variable COMPlus_ThreadPool_ForceMinWorkerThreads to overwrite default MinThreads setting, according to [Environment/Registry Configuration Knobs](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/clr-configuration-knobs.md) - You can also use the same `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads()` method as described above.

#### Sources:

1. [Microsoft Azure - Investigating timeout exceptions in StackExchange.Redis for Azure Redis Cache](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/investigating-timeout-exceptions-in-stackexchange-redis-for-azure-redis-cache/)
2. [StackExchange.Redis](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)

Comment: We've updated to this method but it's not changed anything for us, still same frequency of errors.

Comment: Why do not use ThreadPool.SetMinThreads() in Asp net (framework)?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that there is an issue with network stability - thus the timeouts.

Since nobody has mentioned an increase in the `responseTimeout` I would play around with it.  The default value is **50ms** which can be easily reached.  I would try it around **200ms** to see if that would help with teh messages.

Taken from the [configuration options](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/docs/Configuration.md#configuration-options):

```
responseTimeout={int}   ResponseTimeout     SyncTimeout     Time (ms) to decide whether the socket is unhealthy
```

There are multiple issues opened on this on github.  The one combining all is probably [#871 The "network stability" / 2.0 / "pipelines" rollup issue](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/871)

One more thing: did you try to play around with `ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectAsync()` instead `ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect()`?

### 14.12.2021 - An Update

In *stackexchange.redis v2.2.4*: the following is given for

> 'responseTimeout' : Warning CS0618
> 'ConfigurationOptions.ResponseTimeout' is obsolete: 'This setting no
> longer has any effect, and should not be used

Update was sent by [MX313](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8767516/mx313)

Comment: FYI: in stackexchange.redis v2.2.4:  the following is given for 'responseTimeout' : 
Warning CS0618 'ConfigurationOptions.ResponseTimeout' is obsolete: 'This setting no longer has any effect, and should not be used'

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this timeout error for a while, below steps resolved my problem:

**first** of all, I used `Lazy<T>` for my connection:

```
private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection =  new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
{
   return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(new ConfigurationOptions
          {
               EndPoints = { Url },
               AbortOnConnectFail = false,
               Ssl = UseSsl,
               Password = Password,
           });
});

public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection => lazyConnection.Value;
```

**Second**, I updated all my async methods to sync. for example, I was using `StringGetAsync` so I replaced it with `StringGet`.

**Third**, I changed the minimum number of Thread:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
   ...
   SetupThreadPool();
}

private static void SetupThreadPool()
{
     ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out var workerThreads, out var completionPortThreads);
     ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(workerThreads, completionPortThreads);
}
```

I tested my API by [bombardier](https://github.com/codesenberg/bombardier) (-d 10s -c 125), and I achieved to a zero error state, below is the benchmark:

[image: benchmark]

As you can see all the requests are handled by the application successfully!

I hope it helps.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Have the network traffic monitor switched on to confirm/deny the blip.have a solution to the issue but a crude one. Option 1 - try restarting the managed redis instamce in azure.