# Get a large amount of items (150k+) from Azure Redis

Tags: azure, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm using [CachingFramework.Redis](https://github.com/thepirat000/CachingFramework.Redis) and trying to retrieve a large list or object (over 150k items). Even though I have a very large Azure Redis instance (25 gigs), I get timeout errors if I don't break up the list into smaller sets, each with their own key.  If I break up the list, I still get time out errors when trying to call all the keys to assemble the list.  If I put all the items in one list, I can only get away with a list of about 25k items before it throws an error of 'unsepecified kind'

I've tried using Redis lists and also the ['Collection' implementation](https://github.com/thepirat000/CachingFramework.Redis/blob/master/COLLECTIONS.md) in CachingFramework.Redis.  The Collection implementation is like so:

```
 IRedisSet<List<User>> set = context.Collections.GetRedisSet<List<User>>("users");
```

What is the best way to get 150k + items from Azure Redis client, using the above client or StackExchange Redis?  I need to get all items in less than 200 ms. Is that possible?  Can I create multiple client connections and get chunks on each connection in parallel?

Comment: Have you checked this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51651796/stackexchange-redis-timeout/51980231

Comment: Yes I've looked at those.  My question is more of what is the best practice to get large amounts of data

Comment: How large is each item?

Comment: I don't have it in front of me, but I seem to remember not too big. About 100mb for all items combined

Comment: For that particular list