# StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout awaiting response, command=ping

Tags: redis, azure-aks

We are currently experiencing an error in our logging, it happens occasionally (once a week or so) but it pulls down most of our platform.

I have researched the issue and read some standard things we could try, we have tried most of those in the past without result unfortunately.
I also noticed other people have similar errors but for different reasons, for example;
[StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout awaiting response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57661799/stackexchange-redis-redistimeoutexception-timeout-awaiting-response)
[StackExchange.Redis timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51651796/stackexchange-redis-timeout?rq=1)

I went through https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts
and made sure I can answer all questions to the best of knowledge to try and pin down where the issue might be, but unfortunately I end up at the same starting point each time.

Approximately 6000 errors take place in a timespan of 2 minutes.

The Error first error:

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout awaiting response (outbound=0KiB, inbound=0KiB, 5412ms elapsed, timeout is 5000ms), command=PING, next: PING, inst: 0, qu: 0, qs: 2, aw: False, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 0, in-pipe: 0, out-pipe: 0, serverEndpoint: live-caching-platform-master.live-caching:6379, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: ups-command, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=500,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=45,Free=32722,Min=2000,Max=32767), v: 2.1.58.34321 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts) at HealthChecks.Redis.RedisHealthCheck.CheckHealthAsync(HealthCheckContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

The last error:

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout awaiting response (outbound=0KiB, inbound=0KiB, 5480ms elapsed, timeout is 5000ms), command=PING, next: PING, inst: 0, qu: 0, qs: 39, aw: False, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 0, in-pipe: 0, out-pipe: 0, serverEndpoint: live-caching-platform-master.live-caching:6379, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: sponsoredgames-admin, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=500,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=1,Free=32766,Min=2000,Max=32767), v: 2.1.58.34321 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts) at HealthChecks.Redis.RedisHealthCheck.CheckHealthAsync(HealthCheckContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

The command is always PING which seems to indicate it is a network related issue.
But I am not able to pinpoint what exactly could be the trigger of this.
We host the redis instance in a AKS environment on its own specific nodepool.

Comment: I have the same problem. All recommendations are in place, but still see redis timeouts. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not found a solution yet we contacted Microsoft and they gave us some logging options but we have not had the issue since.